# Melt dummies into one group variable

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

Say I have:

```
df = data.frame(var = rnorm(10), 
           apple = c(rep(1, 5), rep(0, 5)),
           pear = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 3), rep(0, 2)),
           banana = c(rep(0, 8), c(rep(1, 2))))
df

#     var          apple pear banana
# 1   0.83909475     1    0      0
# 2  -0.49670792     1    0      0
# 3  -0.33740589     1    0      0
# 4  -0.94037675     1    0      0
# 5   0.50043212     1    0      0
# 6  -0.05489703     0    1      0
# 7   0.90638714     0    1      0
# 8  -0.01192395     0    1      0
# 9   1.80543603     0    0      1
# 10  0.56456775     0    0      1
```

And I want

```
#     var            Group
# 1   0.83909475     apple  
# 2  -0.49670792     apple  
# 3  -0.33740589     apple
# 4  -0.94037675     apple
# 5   0.50043212     apple
# 6  -0.05489703     pear
# 7   0.90638714     pear
# 8  -0.01192395     pear
# 9   1.80543603     banana
# 10  0.56456775     banana
```

Is there an elegant way to do this with `melt` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with matrix multiplication

```
colnames(df[2:4])[as.matrix(df[2:4]) %*% 1:3]
```

or by selecting the largest column (as the columns are mutually exclusive)

```
colnames(df[2:4])[max.col(df[2:4])]
```

or using `reshape2::melt`

```
m <- melt(df, id.vars='var') 
m[m$value != 0, -3]
```